# How to select input with a certain name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

With

`input[name="abc"]`

but what if the name contains stuff like `[` and `]` ?

My input looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="abc[def][5][xyz][]" value="" />
```

Comment: *sidenote:* why makes the `name` so complicated ?

Comment: i'm supposed to get array in the server script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to escape `[]` if the attribute value is enclosed within `""`

```
$('input[name="abc[def][5][xyz][]"]')
```

Demo link on: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z6JLf/)

Comment: +1 Much simpler solution. Didn't think of this at first.

Answer (score 1):

Use escape characters `input[name=\[def\]\[5\]\[xyx\]\[\]]`.

Comment: hmm is there an escaping function in javascript?

Comment: Yes, of course. Escape characters are very common to see in JavaScript as well as CSS.

Comment: I'm sure Alex is asking if there's a `function` that will do the escaping so that it doesn't need to be done manually.

Comment: Oh, well in that case, no I don't think so. You can't change the design/syntax of a scripting language by using functions.